# How to get value of nearest input Jquery

Tags: jquery, closest

I have multiple buttons on my page with the same class. When I click on a button I want to get the value of the nearest input box (remember there are multiple input boxes and buttons on my page with the same classes).

I have:

```
    $(".deletepostbutton").click(function() {

            var deleteid = $(this).closest('.deleteid').attr('value');

  });


<div class="microblogpostactions">
     <input type="text"  name="deleteid" class="deleteid" value="'.$row['id'].'" />
     <a href="Javascript:void[0]" class="deletepostbutton">Delete</a>
     </div>

<div class="microblogpostactions">
     <input type="text"  name="deleteid" class="deleteid" value="'.$row['id'].'" />
     <a href="Javascript:void[0]" class="deletepostbutton">Delete</a>
     </div>
```

How can I get the value of the nearest input and make my variable equal to it when a user clicks on the link????

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use [`.prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) if you're sure they're right next to each other. (This should be fastest.)

```
 var deleteid = $(this).prev().attr('value');
```

This gets the previous element.

If there's a chance that there will be another element in between, you could use [`.siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/):

```
 var deleteid = $(this).siblings('.deleteid').attr('value');
```

This will get *all* siblings *inside the same `<div>`* with the `deleteid` class.

Answer (score 3):

```
$(this).parent().find('.deleteid').attr('value');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).parent().find('.deleteid').attr('value');
```

It may (and it does) cause problems with perfomance. For example:

```
$(this).parent().find('.deleteid').val(10);
alert($(this).parent().find('.deleteid').val());
```

Sometimes it returns the previous value of .deleteid (not 10)